# Change loaded run configurations default values on intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

When opening a new project, defaults value for run configurations are created with their "default values", I can then change them to comply with my current project. What I am looking for is a way to override the "default values" for every project I open or create here on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, it's not possible until [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148319) is addressed. At the moment default settings from the run/debug configurations are not propagated to the new projects.

Comment: They usually name it stopepd working since intellij 15, I am using 13 and don't get that feature either. Maybe it was introduced on 14 and died there?